# Is this site only for questions?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, asking-questions

Sometimes I have something nice that I wish to publish, and get some feedback or comments about it from the community.

So should I not post it here? Or maybe there is some other platform for this kind of posts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this platform is for reasonably scoped mathematical questions (and answers to them), only.

Questions seeking feedback on material prior to publication are in general not on-topic; typically, they will be "too broad" or they will be "seeking personal advice," two among the reasons for closing a question.

If you have a specific mathematical question related to your unpublished work, which can be stated in a rather self-contained way in a few paragraphs, then it is in principle on-topic.

If you have a specific question about the process of publication, then it is in principle on-topic on the SE site [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com).